# Let $a_n \to +\infty$, and let $b_n \to +\infty$. Show that $a_n + b_n \to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to show $a_n$ diverges, or $b_n$. I know the sum of two convergent limits is the sum of the limits. But how do we show that two divergent limits are divergent?

Comment: Start by writing out the definition of what $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n+b_n = \infty$ really means. This will tell you what you need to prove.

Comment: You cannot in general say the the pairwise sum of two divergent sequences is divergent (e.g. $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$) but you are trying to show something more specific here.

Comment: If $b_n \rightarrow \infty$ then $b_n \neq -n$. My understanding of what OP is saying is that both sequences are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the question is already asked and solved, there is always some thing new about it....Let me give it a try....and you let us know if it suits your taste?...Start out letting $M > 0$ be given, there exists $N_1$ such that: if $n > N_1 \to a_n > \dfrac{M}{2}$, and also $N_2$ such that if $n > N_2 \to b_n > \dfrac{M}{2}$. Thus if $n > N_1+N_2 = N$, then $a_n+b_n > \dfrac{M}{2}+\dfrac{M}{2} = M$, proving that $a_n+b_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two divergent sequences isn't necessarily divergent. For example $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$.

However if they diverge to infinity note that $a_n+b_n>a_n$ for large $n$, and use the comparison test.

Comment: If $b_n \rightarrow \infty$ then $b_n \neq -n$.

Comment: @race bannon agreed.